# Where does okular store it's metadata

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-reader

I want to know where does okular store it's metadata (highlighting and other type of annotations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in

`$(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/okular/docdata/`