# Where does Okular store the PDF annotations?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, annotations, okular

I am using Okular in Ubuntu 11.04 as it has support to annotations and is faster to do a quick find across large documents. The annotations are not stored in the document, but are stored as metadata in some folder. I would like to know where Okular stores the metadata, so that I can create a symlink in Dropbox so that my annotations to the PDF are automatically backed up.

The answer to the below query mentions the location of the metadata in KDE, but I am using GNOME.

[Where does okular store it's metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/200883/where-does-okular-store-its-metadata)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update (thanks to @fifaltra for pointing me to it, see the comments)

The new annotation place is:

> ~/.local/share/okular

they were previously stored by default in xml files located in

> ~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata

or better

> $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/okular/docdata/

regardless of the fact you're using gnome or not.

Comment: For newer systems, see https://askubuntu.com/q/942748/231418

Comment: If you see the link above (user60381's answer), you will find out that for newer systems, the annotations seem to be in the PDF itself, rather than in the xml at `~/.local/share/okular`.